# Can't merge a list of lists using itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

Hello stack overflow friends!

I'm trying to run this code, to download images from urls.

Here's the code:

```
import requests
import itertools
import pandas as pd

lista = pd.read_excel("link_img_bling.xlsx")
lista = lista.values.tolist()
lista2 = list(itertools.chain(lista))




for img in lista2:
    file_name = img.split('/')[-1]
    print(f"This is the file name: {file_name}")
   
    r = requests.get(img, stream=True)
  
    if r.status_code == 200:
        
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r:
                f.write(chunk)
    else:
        
        broken_images.append(img)
```

The problem is when i transform the dataframe into a list, it returns a list of lists and it breaks my file_name variable. So i've tried to concatenate the list using itertools, but it didn't work, it still returns a list of lists.

Any ideas?

Comment: `lista2 = list(itertools.chain(*lista))` this will work

Comment: Better yet, `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lista))`, which can lazily iterate over the list of lists as needed, rather than having to extract each element immediately.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why did you use the *?